# How should we group related tags?

Tags: mongodb, tags

Such as in stack overflow?

I noticed that some tags are synonyms. For example restaurant and restaurants. Some tags are hierarchical. For example, food -> restaurant.

How do you store the data structure in mongodb?

Do you have sets of synonyms where the default is the id?

Also what would you do if user search for restaurant or restaurants, for example?

Do you convert all search into it's default form and search the tag or do you expand the search to all of it's synonym?

What's the standard way?

I am using mongodb.

Comment: There are many dozens of very acceptable ways to store the data, as there is no standard way. For searching, I'd suggest you consider caching the tags in memory in your application and writing the search there as you can significantly improve the quality of the search results (contains, sounds-like, misspellings, etc).

Comment: I am looking for data structure.

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working? This is too general as is. It needs more details. If you had 10 users a minute vs 1000, the answer is different. Maybe MongoDb isn't good for this part. Maybe lucene should be used for matching tags for example.

Comment: I've tried many designs. For example, should this be a tree? if all restaurants are restaurants and all restaurants are food, if people search for food, should restaurants pop out? I think I am making this overly complicated.

Comment: Those choices aren't implementation issues -- you can solve them with any technology really. You need to figure out how you want it to behave. Neo4J might be a good fit if you've got a graph-like experience in mind for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The StackOverflow schema is relational.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) (Specifically [MS SQL Server 2008](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)) It maintains a many-to-many relation between Tags and Posts.  And it maintains a unidirectional relationship of Tags with their synonyms.

Your restaurants example appears to be a classification system where nodes names in the classification may have synonyms.  In this case the data structure of the classification may be more important than the actual node names.  How synonym's are implemented would be highly dependent on the data structure and anticipated query patterns.  Look at the [Data Modeling Patterns docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/#data-modeling-patterns) to see a variety of different data structures.

Mongo doesn't have any name aliasing functionality built into the core DB server.  Some ORM's provide a limited name aliasing capability on the client side.  For example [mongoose through virtual attributes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals).  These should be used with caution though because they don't provide an underlying performance benefit, and may obscure what's really happening in the database.